# SFTP with DefaultSftpSessionFactory by SSH trust throws exception

Tags: java, spring, ssh, sftp, private-key

I have requirement to download/upload all txt file from SFTP server.
I am using Spring configuration as `org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory`
and inbound 
its throws `ServletContext resource not found`.
Here password would be blank

```
<bean id="acceptAllFileListFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter" />


<bean id="inboundSftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="inboundDefaultSftpSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="inboundDefaultSftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}" />
        <property name="privateKey" value="/home/tech/id_rsa"/>
        <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${sftp.private.key.passphrase}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${sftp.port}" />       
        <property name="user" value="${sftp.user}" /> 
        <property name="password" value="${sftp.password}" />
    </bean>
```

....

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/home/tech/id_rsa]

        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)

        at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.initJschSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:371)

        at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:347)

        ... 27 more
```

File is exist at specified location

when i tried with password configuration then its working fine.

Comment: prefix with `file:`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-resourceloader .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file isn't at the specified location, as it tries to load the file from the root of the application and it isn't located there. It is located on the file system but that isn't what you specified.

Prefix the property value with `file:`.

```
<bean id="inboundDefaultSftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}" />
    <property name="privateKey" value="file:/home/tech/id_rsa"/>
    <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${sftp.private.key.passphrase}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${sftp.port}" />       
    <property name="user" value="${sftp.user}" /> 
    <property name="password" value="${sftp.password}" />
</bean>
```

See the reference guide for more information on [resource loading](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-resourceloader).

Comment: yep just to be more precise here is a link to exact resource loading spec -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#resources-implementations